# Is there a way to use India's map on openstreetmap.in instead of the map available on openstreetmap.org?

Tags: maps, openstreetmap

I want the map of India without the territory disputes, as provided by the govt of India(and as shown on openstreetmap.in). Is there a link to download a pbf file for the map or a set of instructions to overlap the tiles in the map?

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/User:SomeoneElse/Ubuntu_1604_tileserver_load#Tile_server_pre-requisite_software

I have used these instructions to setup the map and instead of the map link provided in the instructions, I have used this

http://download.geofabrik.de/asia/india-latest.osm.pbf

This link is available on the openstreetmap.in website but the map is the same as the one on openstreetmap.org

Comment: Did you chrck openstreetmap.in? The data is the same as openstreetmap. Just the style is different.

Comment: The map shown on openstreetmap.in for India is with respect to the boundary guidelines provided by the Govt of India, but the data I downloaded from the website does not comply with the data presented on the website.

Comment: Again: data and representation are different things. openstreetmap.in uses normal openstreetmap data. Just they represent data (so boundary) differently. Check their styles (on github).

Comment: There is also the [OSM talk-in](https://lists.openstreetmap.org/listinfo/talk-in) mailing list.

Comment: Still, neither can I find a way to overlap the existing tiles, nor can I find with what to replace the existing style sheets

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/osm-in/tileserver is what you are searching for.

Answer (score 1):

openstreetmap.in's rendering style can be found here: https://github.com/osmlab/india.tm2

They have special rendering rules for "disputed boundaries":

```
#admin,#boundaries-claimed["@relations"=~'.*"claimed_by":[ ]*"IN".*'] {
  opacity: 0.5;
  line-join: round;
  line-color: #446;
  [maritime=1] {
    // downplay boundaries that are over water
    line-color: @water;
  }
  // Countries
  [admin_level=2],#boundaries-claimed {
    line-width: 0.8;
    line-cap: round;
    [zoom>=4] { line-width: 1.2; }
    [zoom>=6] { line-width: 2; }
    [zoom>=8] { line-width: 4; }
    [disputed=1] { line-dasharray: 4,4; line-opacity:0.5}
  }
  // States / Provices / Subregions
  [admin_level>=3] {
    line-width: 0.3;
    line-dasharray: 10,3,3,3;
    [zoom>=6] { line-width: 1; }
    [zoom>=8] { line-width: 1.5; }
    [zoom>=12] { line-width: 2; }
  }
}

#boundaries-disputed["disputed_by"=~'.*IN.*'] {
  opacity: 1;
  line-join: round;
  line-color: @land;
  [maritime=1] {
    // downplay boundaries that are over water
    line-color: @water;
  }
  // Countries
  [admin_level=2] {
    line-width: 1;
    line-cap: round;
    [zoom>=4] { line-width: 1.5; }
    [zoom>=6] { line-width: 3; }
    [zoom>=8] { line-width: 5; }
  }
}
```

Comment: I added this code to my styles file but I am getting this error            
Styles do not match layer selector #boundaries-disputed.

Comment: See also the [OSM diary entry](https://www.openstreetmap.org/user/PlaneMad/diary/38176) by the author of the style - the "'Fixing' the boundaries of India" section.

Comment: The custom dataset mentioned is not available on mapbox. If there's some other link to it, or some other way I could get access to that data, it would be really helpful